# Does Schwartz kernel theorem come from the universal property of tensor product?

Tags: tensor-products, schwartz-distributions

In wikipedia we have [Tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)

> The tensor product of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is a vector space denoted as $V \otimes W$, together with a bilinear map $\otimes:(v, w) \mapsto v \otimes w$ from $V \times W$ to $V \otimes W$, such that, for every bilinear map $h: V \times W \rightarrow Z$, there is a unique linear map $\tilde{h}: V \otimes W \rightarrow Z$, such that $h=\tilde{h} \circ \otimes$ (that is, $h(v, w)=\tilde{h}(v \otimes w)$ for every $v \in V$ and $w \in W$ ).

we also have [Schwartz kernel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_kernel_theorem)

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Every distribution $k \in \mathcal{D}^{\prime}(X \times Y)$ defines a continuous linear map $K: \mathcal{D}(Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{D}^{\prime}(X)$ such that
> $$
> \langle k, u \otimes v\rangle=\langle K v, u\rangle
> $$
> for every $u \in \mathcal{D}(X), v \in \mathcal{D}(Y)$. Conversely, for every such continuous linear map $K$ there exists one and only one distribution $k \in \mathcal{D}^{\prime}(X \times Y)$ such that (1) holds. The distribution $k$ is the kernel of the map $K$.

Does Schwartz kernel theorem come from the universal property of tensor product?

Comment: So, $(v, w) \mapsto \langle Kv, w\rangle$ defines a bilinear map $D(X) \times D(Y) \to \mathbb{R}$. By the universal property of the tensor product, there exists a linear map $D(X) \otimes D(Y) \to \mathbb{R}$ corresponding to this. However, it is not at all clear from this point of view, that this linear map is continuous and moreover extends continuously to the much larger space $D(X \times Y)$, in order to making it a distibution on $X \times Y$.

Comment: What you need to look into in order to get sensible statements are *topological* tensor products of locally convex spaces. A standard reference on these things is the book "Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels" by Treves.

Comment: There has to be nuclearity (in the lc context) somewhere in the list of ingredients.